# Laravel whitescreen (413 error) when uploading files to S3

Tags: laravel, apache, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, file-upload

When I try to upload my file from the server (AWS EC2) to S3 storage, I get a white screen, and the console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413()
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

On localhost, everything works well, but on server I get those errors. I've tried to increase memory and file upload size limits on php.ini. I run web on apache webserver. Maybe someone could help me?

Code that I'm using:

```
$thumbnailLink = "https://xx.s3.xxxx-1.amazonaws.com/".$folder."/thumbnails/".$thumbnailName;
$s3->put($thumbnailPath, file_get_contents($thumbnail), 'public');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at first, you need to debug the error you're facing. It should be a server error if everything works well on the localhost.

Go to /var/log/apache2 and open error.log to see an error message. There you will find more information about the error you're facing.

```
cd /var/log/apache2/
nano error.log
```

Then I googled my error, and post_max_size was set to only 8MB. I changed that as well with the memory limit, and my errors disappeared.